# Why property types won't compile?

Tags: typescript

There's a model that could be in a wrong state, we can check the errors as `model.getErrors()` the errors is a map with keys of some type `keyof D` and also one special key `base`.

Why this seems to be valid code won't compile? [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20type%20Errors%3CD%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20readonly%20%5BK%20in%20(keyof%20D%20%7C%20'base')%5D%3F%3A%20string%5B%5D%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Model%3CD%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20getErrors()%3A%20Errors%3CD%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%20base%3A%20%5B'some%20base%20error'%5D%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D)

```
export type Errors<D> = {
  readonly [K in (keyof D | 'base')]?: string[]
}

class Model<D> {
  getErrors(): Errors<D> {
    return { base: ['some base error'] }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you will need a type assertion. Typescript is limited in what it will do with unresolved generics. Although in this case the object literal is assignable to the type typescript will not try to prove this and will just issue an error when dealing with a mapped or conditional type that has unresolved generics.

Comment: This actually looks like a TypeScript bug to me. An empty object is accepted, the language service suggests adding `{ base: string[] }`, but once it's done, the error is raised. Something is inconsistent here. May be worth submitting an issue to https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/.

Comment: For anyone coming from Google, this was indeed an error and a fix is ready https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30112

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's [an error](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30081) that should be fixed in the next release of TypeScript